# Intuition behind this solution for "Maximising XOR"

Tags: algorithm, logic, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, xor

Here is the problem statement:

Given two integers: L and R,
find the maximal values of A xor B given, L ≤ A ≤ B ≤ R

Input Format:

The input contains two lines, L is present in the first line. 
R in the second line.

Constraints :
1 ≤ L ≤ R ≤ 1000

Output Format 
The maximal value as mentioned in the problem statement.

Source:
[Maximising XOR](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximizing-xor)

Here is one unique solution to the above:

```
def maxXOR(L,R):
    P = L^R
    ret = 1
    while(P): # this one takes (m+1) = O(logR) steps
        ret <<= 1
        P >>= 1
    return (ret - 1)
print(maxXOR(int(input()),int(input())))
```

Could you please explain the intuition behind this solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Include the problem statement directly in the question. Otherwise, when the link later breaks, no one will have any idea what this question is about.

Comment: Here's a hint - if L and R have a common prefix, then every number between L and R also have the same prefix, and every possible XOR of two such numbers will zero out that prefix. The rest of the bits, after the prefix, take on various values, and the maximum of the XOR of those bits will be any time the two values are complements of each other, which gives an XOR result of all ones. Every possible final result will thus be of the form 2^N-1 for some N. That's actually a pretty slick solution, I would say, although a bit non-obvious... ;-P

Answer (score 1):

There is one simple way using which you can solve the problem in `O(1)`.

Let's start:

- Do the bit-wise XOR of `L` and `R` and store it in a variable say `xored`.
- Then take the `MSB` in the `xored` which is set and make all the bits from that `MSB -----> LSB` as `1` and that is the answer.

Following example which will make things clear.

```
L = 10111 --> (23)   
R = 11100 --> (28)
    _X___  <-- that's most significant differing bit
    01111  <-- here's our final answer i.e. (15).
```

To set all the bits from `MSB` to `LSB`, first calculate the `2^n - 1` where `n = number of bits required to represent L^R` and then do `L^R | (2^(n) - 1)`.

**Solution in Python:**

```py
import math

def main():
    xored = int(input().strip()) ^ int(input().strip())
    print("{}".format(xored | ((1 << (1 + int(math.log2(xored)))) - 1)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**NOTE:** You can refer to solution in `C` and `C++` [**here!**](https://github.com/strikersps/Competitive-Programming/tree/master/Hacker-Rank/Maximizing-XOR).